# Класс в качестве типа метода

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток! У меня возник вопрос, который постоянно меня мучает, хотя я с ним сталкивался всего однажды... Читаю Щилдта, но ответ на свой вопрос никак не могу найти.
Общая форма обьявления метода выглядит следующим образом:

```
*тип имя(список_параметров){
  //тело метода  
}*
```

Если же мы используем в качестве типа метода класс того же метода, что нам это даёт?
Для чего оно надо?
 Заранее благодарю за ясный ответ!

Comment: >Заранее благодарю за ясный ответ!

для получения ясного ответа было бы неплохо задать ясный вопрос. В частности, пояснить, что вы называете типом метода, классом метода и что значит фраза "что нам это даёт?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов несколько. Сразу вспоминается два:

1.Связывание операций в цепочку вызовов. Сравните:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb = sb.append('1');
sb = sb.append('2');
sb.toString();
```

и более лакончиный вариант:

```
new StringBuilder().append('1').append('2').toString();
```

2.Фабричный метод

```
File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("backup", ".tmp");
```